# Is data successfully transferred in UDP even though the buffer sizes are different?

Tags: c, sockets, udp

Or do they have to be equal in order for the data to be sent perfectly at all times?

I am new to socket programming. I wrote a set of codes to send data from one host to another, with the same buffer size for each. And I decreased the receiver's buffer size, then only ascii files are sent properly, not binary ones.

Is the data in the rear cut out if the receiver's buf size if smaller?

Answer (score 4):

From the [recv(3) documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recvfrom):

> For message-based sockets, such as SOCK_RAW, SOCK_DGRAM, and
>   SOCK_SEQPACKET, the entire message shall be read in a single
>   operation. **If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer, and
>   MSG_PEEK is not set in the flags argument, the excess bytes shall be
>   discarded.**

Emphasis added.

Answer (score 2):

The data will be received fine as long as the receiver's buffer is large enough to contain the datagram. If the receiver's buffer is too small, the excess will be discarded.

If you need to know how big the buffer should be, you can call `recv` first with the `MSG_PEEK` flag. The return value will be the size of the full datagram. You can then allocate a big enough buffer, and call it again without this option to receive the packet and remove it from the queue.